# `dispatcher is null` when importing component from local package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-modules

I'm working with a monorepo in which I want to create one folder containing all those little functions as well as components all the separate projects in that monorepo use.

I figured, the best way to do this would be creating a node module in the monorepo and having it export those common functions and components.

Now, when I try to use my exported component from that "common" sub-project, I get messages like this:

```
dispatcher is null
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:162692:7
$@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:158032:34
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:114086:31
...
```

I've created the following setup:

```
common/
  lib/
    components/
      Tooltip/
        index.tsx
    helpers/
      API.ts
      DATETIME.ts
      ...
  index.ts
  ...configs
```

---

index.ts

```
import Tooltip from './components/Tooltip';

export * from './helpers/API';
export * from './helpers/DATETIME';
...

export const COMP = {
  Tooltip: Tooltip
  ...
}
```

*Note:* the wrapping into that const object is to facilitate organization as this library will grow.

---

Tooltip/index.jsx

```
import {FC, ReactElement, cloneElement, useState} from 'react';

export interface ITooltipProps {
  children: ReactElement<any, string>,
  anchor: ReactElement<any, string>
}

const Tooltip: FC<ITooltipProps> = (props: ITooltipProps) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className='tooltip-wrapper' style={{
      position: 'relative',
      display: 'inline-block'
    }}
      onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
      onMouseOver={() => setIsOpen(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsOpen(false)}
    >
      {cloneElement(props.anchor, {className: 'tooltip-anchor'})}
      <div style={{
        visibility: isOpen ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
        zIndex: 10,
        top: '100%',
        left: '50%',
        opacity: isOpen ? 1 : 0,
        transition: 'all ease-in-out 0.3s'
      }}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tooltip;
```

*Note:* I know this "tooltip" is incredibly stupid right now but it just serves as a placeholder to figure out this components-in-separate-package issue.

---

package.json

```
...
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup",
    "ladle": "ladle serve --stories=lib/components/**/*.stories.tsx"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ladle/react": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.63",
    "tsup": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "buffer": "^6.0.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
```

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [ "esnext", "dom" ],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

---

tsup.config.json

```
{
  "splitting": true,
  "sourcemap": true,
  "clean": true,
  "minify": true,
  "dts": true,
  "entry": [
    "lib/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

---

In the other projects in this same repo, this "common"-package is added to dependencies as `"common": "file:../common"`.

Comment: Make sure you don't have multiple versions of react in any of your projects. Check transitive dependencies using your package manager (i.e. run `npm list react`)

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think you may be right. The local `common` package includes it's own node_modules folder including react (devDep). When installing it into the other projects (using `npm i ../common`), it creates a symlink which INCLUDES the local package's node_modules folder and thus its own react. How can I install a local package without it linking the whole folder (eg. excluding node_modules)?

Answer (score 1):

@AluanHaddad was indeed right - the problem was having multiple reacts.

I was installing the `common`-package via `npm i ../common`, which simply creates a symlink to that folder - INCLUDING it's `node_modules`, which, in turn, includes a copy of react.

To fix this, I had to package the `common`-package into a tarball and install that: `npm pack` in the `common`-package and then `npm i ../common/common-1.0.0.tgz` in the consuming projects.

Bonus: automatic updates of that common package can be implemented using something like the following in `package.json`'s scripts:

```
"prebuild":"npm uninstall common && cd ../common && npm run build && npm run package && cd ../back-to-current-project && npm i ../common/common-1.0.0.tgz"
```

This works, as long as the version number of the `common` package does not change.